# How to skip one testcase due to failure of another test case in nunit?

Tags: c#, nunit

I have two methods.
Method1
Method2

If Method1 failes, I want to skip Execution of Method2. How to do that?

(In testNG we achieve this like =>> "@Test(dependsOnMethods = "Method1"))

I tried many solutions using chatGPT, google and bard.
I tried using "Test Dependency", "Extensions", custom methods etc.

Unfortunately, None of them are working.